# MVC3 Form with Preview before save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently developing an application on MVC3 and:

1. I have a form in which the user is completing the form for each
   register.
2. When he click one button the records are passed to the controller
   and stored in a list and then passed to the view again to show a
   preview of what is at the momment in the "buffer"
3. The data which is not edited and only displayed (previous registers) for avoiding  their dissapear are preserverd in the multiple steps using hiddenfor
4. Finally the user can save all the elements on the list in the database when click another button

My question is: there is way to preserving the data in the list without having to make a hiddenfor for every element in each step?

Answer (score 0):

Create a session variable for your list.

```
Session["MyList"] = myList;
```

Later you "restore" your list like this:

```
var myList = Session["MyList"] as List<MyType>;
```

If you add some of your code I can adjust this to fit your exact case.

Comment: I'm going to google about session in order to don't bother you when use the code you give me, if I have a doubt I will ask you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use wizard technique to do this .So first you need to find an wizard plugin.
For example [jQuery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/).
One each step you will have form that you need and the you have two choices:
**to work with Session like this :**

```
   public YourObject GetObjectfromSession()
            {
                var obj = new YourObject();
                if (HttpContext.Session["SessionName"] != null)
                {
                    obj= (VmSysMealCreate)HttpContext.Session["SessionName"];
                }
                return obj;
            }

            public void InsertObjectTOSession(YourObject obj)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Add("SessionName", obj);
            }
```

On each step changing you can validate form and submit it to method in controller where you will save this not to database but to session.And on final step you can make a summary for all you form .
    This is good solution ,this will be very easy to implement and will work nice.But using this solution you need to think about how long you need session to save your data because session will be limited in time.

**Second thing that you can do :**
    Using an wizard plugin, on last step you can get all your forms and for each form you can do something like this:

```
function functionNAme(formId) {

    var form = jQuery("#" + formId);
 if (form.valid()) { //If form is valid
        form.submit();
        return isValid;
    }
    var isValid = false;

    form.submit(function (e) {
        var that = this;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            async: false,
            /* cache: false,*/
            success: function (result) {
               //on post method return result (summary view ofr each form )
              //and you can append it to your last step
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        // unbind form submit event
        form.unbind(e);
        // preventing default
        e.preventDefault();
        // cancel the default submission of the form
        return false;
    });   
}
```

Second solution is good but is not so simple to implement
Hope this will hoe you and  you will make right decision.If you will find anther solution please provide us with it.