# load big form in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-data

I have a big form loaded in asp.net mvc. My form has some pages and each page has some questions and each question has some choices.

I want to load a form and all of its items for a user but it's so large and slow.
There are these choices for me:

1. Cache in server : but for some users questions must be randomly or dynamically chosen.
2. Make html page and store in server

Do you have any solution or any links to get better performance from MVC in loading big forms.

Comment: Take  a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705533/mvc3-form-with-preview-before-save/21723636#21723636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the way you structure your "form pages". I see here two situations: the number of "pages" is known (constant) and relatively small *or* you have an unknown number of "form pages".

In the first case, I would recommend a tab display structure, where each "page" is a tab. The content of each tab would be lazy loaded (using Ajax) when the user selects it. That way you don't have to load all the pages and questions from start. As an additional random thought, the submit button would be disabled until all the questions have been answered; that way, the user cannon submit a "partial form".

In the second case, you could opt for a `Next Page` approach, where you present the user the possibility of navigating to the "next page" of questions. Before loading the next page, you would generate hidden fields containing the results of the current page, so that you don't loose your form data and can successfully submit all your questions and answers.

*Addressing your question points:* When randomness is involved, I see no straight forward solutions. You cannot and should not generate a page for every possible combination available (either static or in cache). This might work for a relatively small number of pages and question but I can't really see it as a viable solution. The scenario you described fits to the "Ajax requests architecture" (I made this expression up, but that's what it basically is: Ajax centric design).

Edit: a third solution would be to serialize all your questions and answers into a Json object and gradually render the questions into your page. The downside of this solution is that you would have to implement a lot of the logic in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry , i don't understand the second case , in the first case i must load all question of a page , i can cache just questions not pages and if it is being necessary i can random questions... can you explain more the second case?

Comment: The second case is very similar to the first one, but you don't have tabs. You would have a single (partial) view. The content of this view would be the current set of questions. After the user answers all the questions, they can pres a button (say "Next page") which saves the current set of questions into hidden fields (so that the data can be posted), or even JavaScript objects, and  loads the next set of questions. You would need to call a controller to "give you" the next set.

Comment: Ok,it's good to implement...BUT...in page 1 i have 20 questions,and when 1000 users open the page 1 then it's a bad time for my site , it is being slowly , what is solution for this?

Comment: If you shift the burden of rendering the questions to the browser by using JavaScript, your application would only have to account for serving the data (maybe in Json format) to the clients. On the client side, excepting the time required to get the questions from the server, the page would load as fast as the browser can generate the page.